# All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(52, 224, 224, 3), (64, 35)]

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting this error and its very weird that the first epoch has been completed satisfactorily and the dimensions do not match in the second epoch.
`All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(52, 224, 224, 3), (64, 35)]`
[see error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3JgS.jpg)

I'm using for first time ImageDataGenerator() with the method flow_from_directory() to get all images from the dataset. This is part of the code where the error I think should be:

```
# generator function - two inputs (images and histogram vector) and one label (OCEAN labels)
def generator(dataset_path, OCEAN_histogram, batch_size):

    gen = ImageDataGenerator()
    gen_faces = gen.flow_from_directory(dataset_path,
                                          target_size = (224, 224),
                                          class_mode = None,
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True)    


    batch_OCEAN = np.zeros((batch_size, 5))
    batch_histogram = np.zeros((batch_size, n_features))

    # loop where we continually feed the nn in batches
    while True:

    # it takes the next batch of images
    batch_faces = gen_faces.next()


    # list with all images names in the current batch
    all_faces = [f.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit('/', 1)[1] for f in gen_faces.filenames]

    for i in range(batch_size):
        batch_OCEAN[i] = OCEAN_histogram[all_faces[i]][0]
        batch_histogram[i] = OCEAN_histogram[all_faces[i]][1]

    # shapes : batch_faces -> (64, 224, 224, 3)  batch_histogram -> (64, 35) batch_OCEAN -> (64, 5)
    yield [ batch_faces, batch_histogram ], batch_OCEAN


train_generator = generator(train_path, train_OCEAN_histogram, batch_size)
validation_generator = generator(validation_path, validation_OCEAN_histogram, batch_size)

# Train model on dataset
print("[INFO] training model...")
custom_vgg_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs = 50, steps_per_epoch = train_size//batch_size,
                               validation_data = validation_generator,
                               validation_steps = validation_size//batch_size, verbose = 1)
```

How can this error be possible? Any ideas pls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you total training samples is 55,796 and if your batch size is 64, you will have 871 steps with 52 remainder. After 871 steps, your generator will return you a tensor with shape of `(52, 224, 224, 3)` during next iteration.

I would suggest after each epoch, shuffle the dataset and only keep `55,796//64` samples in your generator.

Comment: Hi @zihaozhihao ! I tried changing in fit_generator the parameter shuffle to True. But it didn't work. How could I only keep `55796//64` samples in my generator as you said? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this post. https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Comment: Well, the generator in that post is quite different than mine. I apparently solved at least the error, checking the size of every batch and if is different from the variable batch_size, then I do a generator.reset() but I'm not sure at all if this is a real solution. What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't think reset is gonna work. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729107/is-fit-generator-in-keras-supposed-to-reset-the-generator-after-each-epoch.

Comment: In the first post I provided, the idea of generating the batch data may help. Basically, you can write your own logic to produce the batch data in the while loop.